# How to run a zeppelin notebook using REST api and return results in python?

Tags: python, rest, apache-zeppelin

I am running a zeppelin notebook using the following REST call from python:

`import requests
requests.post('http://x.y.z.x:8080/api/notebook/job/2BZ3VJZ4G').json()`

The output is {u'status': u'OK'}

But I want to return some results/exception(if any) from few blocks in the zeppelin notebook to the python script.

I also tried to run only a paragraph in the notebook using

```
requests.post('http://x.y.z.x:8080/api/notebook/job/2BZ3VJZ4G/20160922-140926_526498241').json()
```

and received the same output {u'status': u'OK'}.

Can somebody help me to retrieve the results from zeppelin in python?

Comment: zeppelin 0.6 does not support returning values from the notebook to the script from where the rest calls are made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zeppelin has introduced a synchronous API to run a paragraph in its latest yet to be releases 0.7.0 version. You can clone the latest code form their repo and build a snapshot yourself. URL for API is http://[zeppelin-server]:[zeppelin-port]/api/notebook/run/[notebookId]/[paragraphId]. This will return output of the paragraph after it has run completely.

Answer (score 0):

Even in the API documentation of current unreleased version of Zeppelin 0.8.0 there is no information about how to get output, you can check it here:

[REST API Docs for Zeppelin 0.8.0](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/rest_api/notebook.html#run-a-paragraph-asynchronously)

There is a way to accomplish this using functionality of paragraph publishing described here:

[How can you publishing your paragraph](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/manual/publish.html)

BTW. If You run your paragraph using either API call or Zeppelin GUI the iframe will reload automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In Zeppelin 0.8.0, we can run paragraphs of Notebooks after passing parameters via REST APIs. 
You can create dynamic forms inside the notebook and assign it to a variable which will be used across the notebook.

```
    %pyspark

    input_master = z.input("value", 2) # 2 is default value
    z.put("value_item", input_master) 
    print(input_master) // 2


    %sh
    curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --request POST \
    --data '{"params": {"value" : 6}}' \
    http://[zeppelin-server]:[zeppelin-port]/api/notebook/run/[note-id]/[paragraph-id] 


    %spark

    val value = z.get("value_item") // 6
```

For reference, 
  https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/dynamic_form/intro.html, and
  https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/rest_api/notebook.html.